# SQL Server Alert on Missing Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I’m cleaning out a large database and am going to be removing a lot of stored procedures. I can be pretty certain but not 100% that the SP isn’t being used. How can I be alerted that something is calling a missing stored procedure, and throwing the error:

```
Could not find stored procedure ‘X’
```

Comment: you can check query cache and verify theyre not beinbg used. You can also search GIT or whatever source control software youre using to find the presence of proc calls. '

Answer (score 2):

You could create synonyms for each deleted procedure and substitute a different procedure (with matching parameters).  In the example below the procedure doesn't take any parameters.

The code:

1. create "replacement" proc called 'dbo.test_replacement_proc'
2. exec 'dbo.test_replacement_proc'
3. create "test" proc called 'dbo.test_proc'
4. exec 'dbo.test_proc'
5. drop 'dbo.test_proc'
6. create synonym 'dbo.test_proc' for 'dbo.test_replacement_proc'
7. exec 'dbo.test_proc'

When #4 executes it's the original procedure.  When #7 executes it's the replacement procedure.

```
drop proc if exists dbo.test_replacement_proc;
go
create proc dbo.test_replacement_proc
as
set nocount on;
select 'Could not find stored procedure' replacement_message
go

-- run the proc
exec dbo.test_replacement_proc;

-- Create proc
drop synonym if exists dbo.test_proc;
drop proc if exists dbo.test_proc;
go
create proc dbo.test_proc
as
set nocount on;
select 'This is the text' procedure_message
go

-- run the proc
exec dbo.test_proc;

-- drop procedure
drop proc if exists dbo.test_proc;

-- Create a synonym for the deleted procedure
create synonym dbo.test_proc
for dbo.test_replacement_proc;  
go  

-- run the proc (which is now a synonym for the replacement proc)
exec dbo.test_proc;
```

Output #2

```
replacement_message
Could not find stored procedure
```

Output #4

```
procedure_message
This is the text
```

output #7

```
replacement_message
Could not find stored procedure
```

Comment: Or you could drop and recreate with the same name

Answer (score -1):

Use SQL Server Agent to [create an alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-an-alert-using-an-error-number?view=sql-server-ver15) for error #2812.

You need to create an operator also, and then you can setup a notification for the alert.

See [MSSQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1523/how-to-setup-sql-server-alerts-and-email-operator-notifications/) on how to do it all.